# adb exec-out screencap creating corrupted images

Tags: adb, screen-capture

I am using the command:

```
adb exec-out screencap -p > imagePath.png
```

It was working earlier, but now it sometimes creates corrupted images of size 0 KB. No environmental change had been made, so I don't know what forces of nature are at play here.

Has anyone else also gone through the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
adb exec-out "screencap -p && sleep .1" > imagePath.png
```

Comment: Why does this help?
It seems to fix my issue partially but I need a more reliable fix. Is there some timeout issue?